# Populating variables in a groovy script from a java program

Tags: groovy

I know how to call Groovy code from Java code, but can you, while running Groovy script `script.groovy`, ask a Java program to populate its varabies?

```
// script.groovy
import static org.mydomain.WiseJavaProgram.*;
pleasePopulateMeWithVariables();
println numberOfLegs // 2
// We didn't declare numberOfLegs in our sript, the Java program set it for us.
```

I guess maybe for that `script.groovy` should pass its environment to the `pleasePopulateMeWithVariables` method, but I haven't found how to do that. Is this even possible?

The case where I want to use such behavior: I have `script.groovy`, and also an undefined number of groovy scripts of which Java program knows, but of which `script.groovy` doesn't know, and I want to add what is declared in them to `script.groovy`. Basically those additional scripts are data, for example descriptions of various products and their features. This is easy if you run a Java program that creates GroovyShell and evaluates in it data-scripts and then `script.groovy`, but for me it is necessary that we initially call `script.groovy`, not the Java program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as usual, while asking the question I was one step behind the answer -__-

The "environment" I was searching for is the `Script` object itself, available from `script.groovy` simply as `this`. So:

```
// script.groovy
import static org.mydomain.WiseJavaProgram.*;
populateWithVariables(this);
println numberOfLegs // 2

// WiseJavaProgram.java
public class WiseJavaProgram {
  public static void populateWithVariables(Script script) {
    script.evaluate('numberOfLegs = 2');
    script.evaluate(new File("another.groovy"));
    script.evaluate(new File("yetAnother.groovy"));
  }
}
```